# How to Remove Speaker Output from Microphone Input (Without General Noise Removal)?

Tags: windows, audio, microphone, speakers

Given a setup running Windows 11 on a desktop computer with a microphone and a set of room speakers, how can I set up a software filter to remove the audio being played back on those speakers from the audio recorded from the microphone?

In the current year 2023, software algorithms for accomplishing this are readily available in most call applications (e.g. Discord, Zoom). These applications have settings to enable them to automatically remove their own audio output from the audio they send to other call participants.

I am looking for software that can apply this type of audio removal algorithm on a system-wide basis rather than just within the scope of the single application.

For instance, I want to also remove the audio from a video being played back on a second monitor during a call.

I am not interested in "general" noise removal tools -- i.e. any software that attempts to remove "unwanted" portions of the input based on a blind model of what "unwanted" means (unless this portion of the functionality can be separately disabled). The limitations of dynamic range and signal to noise ratio may make some kinds of ambient sounds unrecoverable from underneath much louder audio; this type of limitation is not a problem, but I am looking for software that can be configured to only remove the speaker-to-microphone feedback with reference to the audio signal being output to those speakers.

I am not interested in wearing headphones. This is the solution I already use. I am looking specifically for a solution for audio played through my room speakers.

How can I configure Windows 11 with appropriate software for removing all system audio output from the system audio input?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to remove the *electronic* signal coming into an audio call, or from the user's mic. It is **not** as easy to remove background *audio* noise, since it is shaped by the room's acoustics.

The best way to remove background noise is using a [noise-canceling microphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-canceling_microphone), which discriminates between the sound hitting a mic element near the person's mouth, and an element picking up external noise. Effectively, it subtracts the noise: [signal + noise] - [noise] = signal.

Some are more effective than others. Consult reviews, such as [HowToiSolve](https://www.howtoisolve.com/best-noise-canceling-mic/) or [Digital Itinerant](https://digitalitinerant.com/nomadism/best-noise-canceling-microphone-for-digital-nomads/), and buy from a source that allows returns.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question. It doesn't matter if you think this is easy or not, there is already a setting in many common communcations/calling apps that successfully removes all of speaker-to-microphone feedback generated from that app's own audio.

Comment: Removing stray audio that is already passing through the app is considerably easier to remove than something random outside that known field. Multiple mic arrays are the standard way to handle this - whether it's in your phone or a multi-focussed array designed for conferences.

Comment: @AJMansfield,  "that app's own audio" is a misstatement. As was mentioned in the answer, and as Tetsujin reiterates, it's the *electronic audio channel* that is removed, not *sound*, i.e., audio in the room.

Comment: @Tetsujin Neither of you knows what you are talking about. I am able to have all of the other Discord call participant's audio played through my room speakers and can 100% confirm that the raw unprocessed audio from my microphone contains their voices, yet the audio the other participants receive contains only my voice, nothing of an echo from their own voice or of other participants in the background of the audio stream they receive hundreds of milliseconds later from my client. These apps are _absolutely_ processing that raw mic signal to remove that component from the stream they transmit.

Answer (score 0):

I just found and tested [Solicall Pro](https://solicall.com/solicall-pro/) for this purpose. They call this functionality "[Acoustic Echo Cancellation](https://solicall.com/echo-cancellation-art-or-science/)", and when the Echo Cancellation function is enabled it is able to near-completely remove any background music or other sounds relayed through its virtual audio output device from the virtual microphone input it presents back to the system, i.e. exactly the task described.

Unfortunately, this software is only available for a 3 day free trial, and the minimum purchase quantity is 20 licenses, placing it somewhat out of reach for me as a permanent solution.